# Linked list in C , Can't insert and display node

Tags: c, function, linked-list, singly-linked-list, definition

I tried to implement the linked list but couldn't make out what is actually going wrong that it isn't showing the expected result? I tried to trace the control flow of the program by putting in random `printfs` at suspicious places...

I tried to trace the control and realized that after inserting the first node the changes are not getting reflected in the original linked list; after getting back to `main()` the linked list is empty again!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

int count(struct node *q);
void append(struct node *q, int item);
void display(struct node *q);
void add_after(struct node *q, int item, int pos);
void add_beg(struct node *q, int item);
int delete(struct node *q);

int main()
{
    struct node *p = NULL;
    int item,count,i;

    printf("Enter the element to insert\n");
    scanf("%d",&item);

    append(p,item);

    printf("Control\n");
    printf("%d",p);

    display(p);


    //printf("No. of elements in Linked list = %d",count(p));

    // printf("Enter number of elements: ");
    // scanf("%d", &count);

    // for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
    // {
    //     printf("Enter %dth element: ", i);
    //     scanf("%d", &item);
    //     append(p,item);
    // }

    //printf("No. of elements in Linked List are : %d",count(p));

    return 0;
}

void append(struct node *q, int item)
{
    struct node *temp=NULL  , *new=NULL;

    temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    if(q==NULL)  //Condition for empty linked list
    {
       // procedure to insert first node
        temp->data = item;
        temp->link = NULL;
        q = temp;
        //printf("iz here");
    }
    else 
    {
        //printf("ABCD\n");
        temp = q;
        while(temp->link!=NULL)
        temp = temp->link;

        new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new->data = item;
        new->link = NULL;
        temp->link = new;
    }
}

void display(struct node *q)
{
    // printf("Hitesh");
    //printf("%d",q);

    while(q->link!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",q->data);
        q = q->link;
    }
}

int count(struct node *q)
{
    int c=0;
    while(q->link!=NULL)
    {
        q=q->link;
        c++;
    }
    return c;   
}

void add_after(struct node *q, int item, int pos)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp , *new ;
    temp=q;

    for(i=0;i<pos;i++)
    temp = temp->link;

    new=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->data = item;
    new->link = temp;
    temp = new;
    q = temp;
}

void add_beg(struct node *q, int item)
{
    struct node *temp;
    temp=q;
    temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = item;
    temp->link = q;
    q=temp;
}
```

Note: I have not cleaned comments from the code in order that you can see what things I have done to check what's happening.

Comment: Also sorry for any missing details or bad English , Actually asking first time on stack overflow and i believe that i will get the solution !  Thank You !

Comment: Instead of using random printf's, try to learn to use a debugger

Comment: Sure , Will definitely learn that ! Thank you for the suggestion !

Comment: You create one struct, but in your `display` method you check for `q->link != NULL` which is a logical equivalent to "while q got a next element". This condition will never be true for a linked list with one element.

Comment: @Trickzter I also tried to run loop like this , while(q) but then also it is not working ! Also in main function if a use a loop to insert several nodes and then display ( Check comments in main ) then also it is not working , moreover control is never even reaching the else part of append function , Can u explain why ?

Comment: @HiteshGarg I probably can, check `Vlad from Moscow`s answer

Comment: your loop is not going inside this 'while(q->link!=NULL)'. Please check the condition. It comes out of the loop and directly return c which is '0'.

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir! Yes , that is happening because linked list is always getting NULLED as soon as control gets back to the main function from append function ! My main concern is that only , why the changes are not actually reflected in main function ?

Comment: the compiler outputs this message: `untitled.c:28:14: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct node *’ [-Wformat=]` for this statement: `printf("%d",p);`  which is critical You need to correct this problem

Comment: regarding this function: `void append(struct node *q, int item)`  need to pass a pointer to a pointer to 'q' because C passes by value not by reference  I.E.  `void append(struct node **q, int item)`  And should be called via: `append( &p,item );`  This will result in several other changes to the function.

Comment: regarding: `printf("%d",p);`  This is trying to display an integer, but the parameter is a pointer

Comment: regarding: `  while(q->link!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",q->data);
        q = q->link;
    }`  This loop will exit if the queue only has a single entry and may not display the last entry in the queue

Comment: Ohh , Got it ! Thanks mate !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These functions

```
void append(struct node *q, int item);
void add_after(struct node *q, int item, int pos);
void add_beg(struct node *q, int item);
```

pass the pointer to a node by value. So any changes of the pointer within the functions do not influence on the original pointer.

You should declare the functions like

```
void append(struct node **q, int item);
void add_after(struct node **q, int item, int pos);
void add_beg(struct node **q, int item);
```

For example the function `append` could be defined the following way

```
int append( struct node **head, int item )
{
    struct node *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct node ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->data = item;
        new_node->link = NULL;

        while( *head != NULL ) head = &( *head )->link;

        *head = new_node'
    }

    return success;
}
```

and called like

```
struct node *head = NULL;
//...
append( &head,item );
```

These functions

```
void display(struct node *q)
{
    // printf("Hitesh");
    //printf("%d",q);

    while(q->link!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",q->data);
        q = q->link;
    }
}

int count(struct node *q)
{
    int c=0;
    while(q->link!=NULL)
    {
        q=q->link;
        c++;
    }
    return c;   
}
```

are also invalid because there is no check whether the pointer `q` is equal to `NULL`.

They can be defined the following way

```
void display( struct node *head )
{
    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->link )
    {
        printf( "%d->", head->data );
    }
}

size_t count( struct node *head )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    for ( ; head != NULL; head = head->link )
    {
        ++n;
    }

    return n;   
}
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for answering sir ! One thing i couldn't still really make out that why can't we make it with single * ? i mean all the changes we are making are actually happening at address of original linked list then why we need to create one more link to it by ** ?

Comment: @HiteshGarg You are passing the pointer by value. So the functions deal with a copy of the pointer. Any changes of the copy do not influence on the original pointer. For example initially the original pointer is equal to NULL. You are assigning to a copy of the pointer the address of allocated memory. However the original pointer is not being changed.

Comment: Ohh , Got it ! By the way can't we just use a return statement to make changes in main function ? i

Comment: @HiteshGarg Yes we can.

Comment: Then we won't be needing this double ** concept right ?

Comment: @HiteshGarg Yes, you are right because in this case we are returning a new value of the pointer from the function and can use it to reassign the original pointer.

Comment: Thank You for the help sir !